# load html tag div in colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show the template '.ajax' in colorbox.If I define the template in html page and called in color box its working.when I tried to create a template in jquery and called in colorbox its not working.
working in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34v22/610/) 
not working [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/34v22/614/) (want to work as template called in javascript)

**html**

```
<div class="ajax"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"/>
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.colorbox({inline:true, href:".ajax", onClosed: function() {
$('.ajax').hide()

}});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your html template in a seperate file...or you can call it directly

```
// Called directly, without assignment to an element:
$.colorbox({href:"thankyou.html"});

// Called directly with HTML
$.colorbox({html:"<h1>Welcome</h1>"});
```

so for you it would be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.colorbox({inline:true, href:"template.html", onClosed: function() {
$('.ajax').hide()

}});
});
```

according to colorbox's official documentation.